# SQL Server : get Count() of a related table column where some condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given tables `CollegeMajors`

```
| Id | Major       |
|----|-------------|
| 1  | Accounting  |
| 2  | Math        |
| 3  | Engineering |
```

and `EnrolledStudents`

```
| Id | CollegeMajorId | Name            | HasGraduated |
|----|----------------|-----------------|--------------|
| 1  | 1              | Grace Smith     | 1            |
| 2  | 1              | Tony Fabio      | 0            |
| 3  | 1              | Michael Ross    | 1            |
| 4  | 3              | Fletcher Thomas | 1            |
| 5  | 2              | Dwayne Johnson  | 0            |
```

I want to do a query like

```
Select 
    CollegeMajors.Major,
    Count(select number of students who have graduated) AS TotalGraduated,
    Count(select number of students who have not graduated) AS TotalNotGraduated
From 
    CollegeMajors
Inner Join 
    EnrolledStudents On EnrolledStudents.CollegeMajorId = CollegeMajors.Id
```

and I'm expecting these kind of results

```
| Major       | TotalGraduated | TotalNotGraduated |
|-------------|----------------|-------------------|
| Accounting  | 2              | 1                 |
| Math        | 0              | 1                 |
| Engineering | 1              | 0                 |
```

So the question is, what kind of query goes inside the `COUNT` to achieve the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select CollegeMajors.Major
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN EnrolledStudents.HasGraduated= 0 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "TotalNotGraduated",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EnrolledStudents.HasGraduated = 1 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "TotalGraduated"
From CollegeMajors
InnerJoin EnrolledStudents On EnrolledStudents.CollegeMajorId = CollegeMajors.Id
GROUP BY CollegeMajors.Major
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **CASE** statement inside your **COUNT** to achieve the desired result.Please try the below updated query.

```
Select CollegeMajors.Major
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN EnrolledStudents.HasGraduated= 0 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "TotalNotGraduated",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EnrolledStudents.HasGraduated = 1 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "TotalGraduated"
From CollegeMajors
InnerJoin EnrolledStudents On EnrolledStudents.CollegeMajorId = CollegeMajors.Id
GROUP BY CollegeMajors.Major
```

Comment: No, you need to have group by, i actually did not try to execute your query, i just reposted your code with the way to compute the count with conditions using CASE statement. You need to have group by in the main query and you could consider only the count statement as my answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, initially i had just posted the count section based on his question, later i just updated the entire query without checking his other part of the query. As per your suggestion, i have now updated the query with group by.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for graduated count:

```
Select Count(*) From EnrolledStudents group by CollegeMajorId having HasGraduated = 1
```

And change 1 to zero for not graduated ones:

```
Select Count(*) From EnrolledStudents group by CollegeMajorId having HasGraduated = 0
```